# Sort a strings based on the string patterns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, stringr

I have a data.frame that looks like `df`. 
I want to sort the genes columns so that they start with the `AT1G...` pattern.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(genes=c("18S","ACLA","AT1G25240","AT1G25241","AT1G25242"), functions=c("ribosome","dunno","flowering","O2","photosynthesis"))
df
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   genes     functions     
#>   <chr>     <chr>         
#> 1 18S       ribosome      
#> 2 ACLA      dunno         
#> 3 AT1G25240 flowering     
#> 4 AT1G25241 O2            
#> 5 AT1G25242 photosynthesis
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I want my data to look like this:

```
genes       functions
AT1G25240    flowering
AT1G25241    O2
AT1G25242    photosynthesis
ACLA         dunno
18S          ribosome
```

Any idea or help is highly appreciated it!
The rationale is that I want from a huge data set to see first the core genes that start with AT..

Comment: What is the rationale for string not starting with the pattern?

Comment: Great point Mäel. I am adding it to the question. Thank you so much

Comment: What about those with the patterns? do they need to be sorted as well? ie. 25240 before 25241?

Comment: Preferentially yes! another good point Mäel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you sort (`arrange`) by the presence of the pattern using `grepl`, then `FALSE` (pattern not found) sorts first. If we negate that pattern, we get what you want:

```r
df %>%
  arrange(!grepl("^AT1G", genes))
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   genes     functions     
#   <chr>     <chr>         
# 1 AT1G25240 flowering     
# 2 AT1G25241 O2            
# 3 AT1G25242 photosynthesis
# 4 18S       ribosome      
# 5 ACLA      dunno
```

You can add other arguments to `arrange` for secondary sorts, e.g., `arrange(!grepl(..), genes, functions)`.

Comment: this is beautiful!